# Migrating from NTEXT to NVARCHAR(MAX)

Tags: sql-server, datatypes, alter-table, type-conversion

I have table with the columns of type `NTEXT`. And for some peculiar reasons, the client wants to migrate the column type to `NVARCHAR(MAX)`.

While doing so, what all potential threat should I be careful about?

Is there any possibility of data loss for the `NVARCHAR(MAX)` limitations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. You can alter your tables (Sql 2005+) [cf this](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/05/26/sql-server-2005-replace-text-with-varcharmax-stop-using-text-ntext-image-data-types/).

Or, for your convenience:

```
alter table my_table alter column my_ntext_column nvarchar(max);
```

Or you can supply a view which casts the `ntext` columns to `nvarchar(max)` to make the client happy and leave your database unchanged.

Comment: It would help to note that while you will not lose any data, by only specifying the datatype, it is possible to lose a `NOT NULL` setting and/or have the collation changed if it is not the same as the database's default collation. Please see my post "[Beware! Beware of Unintended Changes When Altering Columns!](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2019/01/15/beware-beware-of-unintended-changes-when-altering-columns/)" for full details and examples.

Answer (score 7):

"peculiar reason"? Only that ntext is deprecated and damn difficult to work with?

It's a lossless conversion. If you are unsure, use the SSMS GUI designer to generate scripts for you.

Answer (score 2):

> *Is there any possibility of data loss for the NVARCHAR(MAX) limitations?*

No. [`NVARCHAR(MAX)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql) allows for twice as much text (2^31-1 vs. 2^30-1) as [`ntext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql).